# Android Screen Orientation: Portrait doesn't work

Tags: android, layout, screen-orientation

I want my Activity to run only in portrait mode, so i tried different things, but none of them worked... here they are:

manifest:

```
<application
        android:name=".App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="intent.to.front" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Didn't work, still could rotate, even if my phone had screen rotation turned off.

next I tried from code. removed added staff from manifest, and wrote this in mainactivity class:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        Utilities.setLocale(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

here's my layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true" tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include layout="@layout/app_bar_main" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/grey"
        android:layout_gravity="start" android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main" app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

result was: It doesn't let me rotate, but when I do, whole app freezes and can't do anything until I rotate it back to portrate.

Help me guys!

Comment: I used same android:screenOrientation="portrait" only to make my app only in portrait mode... Nothing else magic there.. But i have specified this for every activity

Comment: ok guys, i figured out that android:screenOrientation="portrait" and confichanges work for every other activities, but mainactivity

Answer (score 1):

> When you declare one of the landscape or portrait values, it is
>   considered a hard requirement for the orientation in which the
>   activity runs. As such, the value you declare enables filtering by
>   services such as Google Play so your application is available only to
>   devices that support the orientation required by your activities. For
>   example, if you declare either "landscape", "reverseLandscape", or
>   "sensorLandscape", then your application will be available only to
>   devices that support landscape orientation. However, you should also
>   explicitly declare that your application requires either portrait or
>   landscape orientation with the  element. For example,
>   . This
>   is purely a filtering behavior provided by Google Play (and other
>   services that support it) and the platform itself does not control
>   whether your app can be installed when a device supports only certain
>   orientations.

If you would like to ignore this error, do the following:

```
    <activity
        android:name="YourActivity"
        ...
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity">
```

You can read activity attributes in **[this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element)** page

Answer (score 0):

Adding `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` could simply do the trick :

```
<activity android:name=".YourActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Comment: as i said i tried it in first place, but still doesnt work. i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

**First**

> Check your **theme styles** if you have code there for screen orientation, if so remove it.

**Then Remove**

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="intent.to.front" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

I have no idea why you using this. Try removing it and check

Comment: <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: why you using the other intent-filter?

Comment: i don't really remember, sorry. but i tried removing it, still doesn't help

Comment: okk..try adding in you theme style <item name="android:screenOrientation">portrait</item>

Comment: i commented out my main activity code, and it worked, i guess its something there, thought it is too big to post here, i hope to find it. thanks for help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

PORTRAIT   `YourActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);`

LANDSCAPE     `YourActivity.this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);`

Comment: try : setContentView before    setRequestedOrientation

Comment: You cant post Logcat.

Answer (score 0):

When you use :

setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

This commend ignore all settings for orientations that are in manifest file ,even if screen rotation was off, it will rotate.

You must first remove this command from onCreate method then write this to your manifest, and it will work:

```
   <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: man, you didn't read description well. that was 2nd thing i tried, as i said i removed added lines from manifest file. before that i tried this, without even adding code: setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); to main activity class. something weird is happening

Answer (score -1):

Though it might not be obvious to some; if you are using a remote device (using wifi), you will need to uninstall the app and then reinstall it via the wire. Hopefully this will fix your issue.